# Failed to build ios project with CorePlot

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I'm new to ios. I want to use CorePlot in my project.

I followed the steps in the instruction from CorePlot wiki and tried to build my project by Xcode 3.2.2. But i got some errors like

"'CALayer' may not respond to '-encodeWithCoder:' ",
"'NSMutableSet' may not respond to '-sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:'".

I tried to build the examples in the coreplot source code package and got the same errors. 
Anyone knows the reason? How can i solve these problems? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Core Plot projects are set up for Xcode 4.2. You may have to adjust some of the build settings to get them to work in older versions. I don't have that version of Xcode installed any more, but the first thing I would check is to make sure the Base SDK is set to one that you have instead of the generic "Latest iOS".